# What is "dequeue cell"

Tags: ios

Can you help me explain detail about "dequeue cell", and what is "resize properly" in the [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) method?

Comment: You should start by reading the "[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)" in the documentation. It's all explained there.

Comment: in very short: tableviews recycle the cells they show to save on rebuilding the cell from scratch every time which wastes processing power. so if you have 100 cells in your table, but only actually have 5 visible at one time, when a cell goes out the screen it recycles it (queues it) and uses it for one coming in (dequeues it), instead of creating 100 cells in memory. but as rmaddy said, you should read the guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dequeue cell :- returns a reusable table-view cell object for the specified reuse identifier and adds it to the table.

Creating Table View Cells

- registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:
- registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Refer apple document for more description on these delegate methods,
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

This is the way you add the dequeue cell method for the table view in the method *cellforrowatindexpath*.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%i%i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    }    
    return cell;
}
```

This is the resize properly method and what it does.

`- (__kindof UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); 
    // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered`

And here is a tutorial for the same table view dequeue cell in swift
https://thatthinginswift.com/table-data-sources/

http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/